# Frattini subgroup in abelian group

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, maximal-subgroup, frattini-subgroup

Let $G$ a abelian group. I recall that $G^p=\{g^p:g\in G\}$ ($p$ is primes) and $\Phi(G)$ is Frattini supgroup of $G$ i.e. intersection of maximal subgroup of $G$.

I want proof that $\Phi(G)=\displaystyle\bigcap\limits_{p\in\mathbb{P}}G^p$.

$(\supseteq)$ Let $M<\hspace{-2mm}\cdot$ $G$ (i.e. maximal subgroup of $G$) then $\lvert G:M\rvert=p$ for some $p\in\mathbb{P}$, then $G^p\le M$.
Therefore $\displaystyle\bigcap\limits_{p\in\mathbb{P}}G^p\le\Phi(G)$.

I ask help for $(\subseteq$). Thanks

Comment: Work Sylow by Sylow. Much easier.

Comment: $G/G^p$ is an elementary abelian $p$-group, so if $g \not\in G^p$ for some prime $p$, then there is a maximal subgroup $M$ with $G^p \le M$ and $g \not\in M$, so $g \not\in \Phi(G)$.